# Angular component inside angular component? `<comp0><comp1></comp1></comp0>`

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-template

I've tried with `ng-template` and with `ng-container`, but I can't figure out how to include a component inside a component…

```typescript
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  //  template: `<h1>Hello</h1><div>I am in a div<ng-container></ng-container>; now this is end</div>`,
  template: `<h1>Hello</h1><div>I am in a div<ng-template></ng-template>; now this is end</div>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {}


@Component({
  selector: 'intestines',
  template: 'Eww',
  styles: []
})
export class IntestinesComponent  {}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<hello><intestines></intestines></hello>`,
  styles: [ 'p { font-family: Lato; }' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2b2yl3

Comment: Do: ```template: `<h1>Hello</h1><div>I am in a div<ng-content></ng-content>; now this is end</div>`.```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-content`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello</h1><div>I am in a div<ng-content></ng-content>; now this is end</div>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {}
```

Also check [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/everything-you-need-to-know-about-ng-template-ng-content-ng-container-and-ngtemplateoutlet-4b7b51223691/) may be useful for you.